# What do you think of a regular chat event called Project Update Thursday?

Tags: discussion, chat, site-promotion

In my [last question](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/371/how-do-you-feel-about-my-site-promotion-ideas), I mentioned a regular chat event as a way of getting more support for a DIY blog. Starting a regular chat event would demonstrate commitment as well as our ability to provide content.

So, I'm proposing this: next week on Thursday, we'll set up a Chat Event called "Project Update Thursday" that will run from, uh, 19:00 GMT/UTC to 23:59 GMT/UTC. That way we have evening in Europe and midafternoon to early evening in most of the US covered. That should pretty much include most of our users. **If you have a better time suggestion, let me know!**

I was thinking this would be something we did all official-like for a couple of weeks' chats and then allowed to grow organically. We don't want to smack our users in the face with the chats *every week* or else they'll stop noticing the notifications, but a couple weeks' promo should be okay.

Any opinions? Any? ...Bueller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The time you suggest is good - covering the two main time zones of the site (as far as I can see from the top users).

I agree that a having it every week could be seen as a chore if we're not careful. We can schedule it but if not enough people turn up or there's nothing new to report we can just say "hi" and leave.

Comment: I'd like to just have it be an official site event for maybe two weeks and then just let it grow organically. One of us will definitely pop in to start the event and everything. I'll probably stick around and haunt the event while I'm at it, too.