# What should our flyers / handouts say?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

So one of my [site promotion ideas](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/371/how-do-you-feel-about-my-site-promotion-ideas) involved making up flyers or business cards that our users (that is, you guys) could tack up on community boards and leaves places and so forth. We at CHAOS were thinking we could make these digital, so that y'all could print 'em out yourselves and tack 'em up wherever they needed to go.

Jin, our designer, and I were talking and he asked what kind of text we wanted on the flyer itself. Needless to say, the question flummoxed me. So I'm taking it to the community: what do we want the flyer to say?

Incidentally, for the near term, I figured we'd "steal" the look of the back of the DIY business card design:

[image: screencap of the back of the diy card pdf file]

Answer (score 10):

> Measure twice. Cut once. Ask first.

Comment: very nicely done!

Answer (score 2):

> Helping Do-It-Yourselfers do it right. Since 2010.

Answer (score 2):

It should have a [QR code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_code) with the website's URL:

[image: QR code for diy.se]

Or alternatively, a [High Capacity Color Barcode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_Capacity_Color_Barcode) (aka Microsoft Tag) such as this one from Wikipedia:

[image: HCCB or Microsoft Tag]

Answer (score 1):

How about something along the lines of:

> If you get stuck installing that bathroom/kitchen/light/toilet seat you've just bought head over to http://diy.stackexchange.com for some friendly advice from the experts - those who've been in the same position as you.

Though it might be a bit wordy for the business card ;)

Improvements welcome & I'm sure someone else can do better.

Answer (score 1):

"We've already asked the Home Depot employees so you don't have to."

"There is no such thing as DIY electrical work, only potential Darwin Award nominees."

Answer (score 1):

How about a series of cards, specific to different areas of home improvement. They could be based on the most popular tags.

Ex.

Plumbing

> Leaky Pipes? 
> diy.StackExchange.com

Answer (score 0):

> Before you measure, or cut... Ask!

Though that might sound like you're promoting Ask.com???