# Do you all like Project Update Thursday?

Tags: discussion, chat, site-promotion

Now that we've had two Project Update Thursday sessions, I figured I'd ask: how are we liking them? I intend to continue them (they've got multiple net benefits, [which I've mentioned before](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/371/how-do-you-feel-about-my-site-promotion-ideas)) but I'm curious to see if y'all are enjoying them.

Our [first Project Update Thursday](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111/conversation/project-update-thursday-01) was pretty successful.

> - @KarlKatzke talked us through a kitchen restoration that he took part in.
> - @BMitch went through his list of small home projects he has to do.
> - We talked about the Texas heat a bit.
> - Veered into programming territory temporarily.
> - Discussed who to bring into the site, and how we can get them here.
> - I updated the participants about our site traffic following the YHL giveaway.
> - @RebeccaChernoff came in and explained the site blog implementation system.
> - The room suggested blog topics.
> - I chatted about my ideas and projects for promoting DIY.

The [second chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111/conversation/project-update-thursday-02) was pretty successful as well.

> - @KarlKatzke talked about his wiring project.
> - @chris and @JayBazzuzi joined us.
> - @JayBazzuzi talked about and asked for advice about his yurt project.
> - There was also discussion of "little helpers," or children/animals that one has around when doing projects. Said "helpers" are often not as helpful as they ought to be. Some (read: those with opposable thumbs) can be trained to be helpful.

I should have done recaps/notes sooner but I've been distracted by a million and one other things, sorry! But I do think these are good; we've seen more people in these scheduled chats each time. I enjoy them (though I can't always stay til the end) and Thursdays are generally a good night for me to be monitoring a fun, kinda rambly chat.

***EDIT*** Our [third Project Update Thursday](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111/conversation/project-update-thursday-03) happened last night.

> - Prior to the chat, we were talking about tools for an upcoming promotional giveaway. I'll pass along more information once I have it. :)
> - The discussion opened, with, oddly, some sysadmin love. So, who says we don't have crossover appeal?
> - Most of our participants this week didn't really have any major project updates.
> - @RebeccaChernoff came back in (she keeps getting pulled into these, haha) to chatter about the mechanics and the finer points of a DIY blog. To me, it feels like we're that much closer to one.
> - @BMitch showed us before/afters of his recent project. We talked about blinds for a while.
> - We chatted about DIY mishaps -- not the bloody kind! The kind that are funny; cutting speed squares, the cord of the saw, etc.
> - And then the chat was quiet til the end.

Since this seems to be a regular phenomenon -- that the end of the chat is pretty silent - @ChrisF and I have decided to shorten the length of the chat itself. In addition, two other changes will take place. First, this week was the chat-cast sans the system message. We had a lower turnout (though the regulars were all there!) and I'd like to keep bringing in new faces. So, the chat-cast will be [an official event](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/111/home-improvement?tab=schedule) until the end of the year. **Register yourself!** Second, we'll have a house ad going up on the site advertising the event during off-hours. I'll try to get those up later.

One other thing: should this be Project Update Monday instead? I noticed in our analytics that Monday is our highest-traffic day of the week, historically. Thoughts? ***/EndEdit***

Have any of your encountered any problems with the chat? How are you liking them so far?

(PS: If I've messed up your name, let me know and I'll fix it; I'm writing this really fast!)

Comment: Looking at how they bring more than one person to the chat room *per week*, they're a resounding success!

Answer (score 1):

I like the idea of Monday evenings better. Thursday evenings tend to be busy for business travelers that go home then. That, and presumably most of our projects are done over the weekend.

Answer (score 0):

I think they're a pretty decent success. I think the end of the chat is going to be quiet once everyone has checked in and talked about their current updates... I don't know that there's a "solution" to that except to move the time of the chat so that those in the US can move on to other important home improvement topics, like what beer tastes best after a home improvement project.

Answer (score 0):

Tonight's (13th October) chat can be found [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111/conversation/project-update-thursday-13th-oct-2011)

Check either side of the official start and end as I think there were ongoing discussions that overflowed the chat itself.